# Power bi Embedded visuals from different pbi reports

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am using power bi embedded (aka app owns data) in an asp.net mvc app, is there any way to call many visuals from differents pbi reports using one api call?

Comment: What do you mean "to call many visuals from differents pbi reports using one api call"? You can embed individual tiles from a dashboard, so if you pin these to a dashboard, you can embed some of them or the whole dashboard and in the later case you will embed a single item, so you can do that with "one api call".

Comment: Hi @AndreyNikolov , i dont want to embed tiles from  dashboards, i want to embed visuals from pbi reports, each report is in a different workspace in the same pbi account.
I tried with tiles, but visuals look better, especially with market place's visuals, and it has more options in the javascript api.

Comment: You cannot embed individual visuals from a report, only whole reports, whole dashboards, or individual tiles from dashboards.

Comment: You  can embed dashboards, pbi reports, paginated reports, dashboards tiles, pbi reports visual and q&A.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embed-visual